# How does repulsive gravitomagnetic force fit in with general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, forces

Two masses when in motion must repel each other in additional to the stronger attractive force according to special relativity.
This will make the force much weaker and will contribute to time dilation.

But how does this "gravitomagnetic" force fit in with general relativity?

i.e, How does the curvature of spacetime cause this repulsion?

Comment: By linearizing the Einstein tensor and then working in the harmonic gauge, Einstein's equations take a surprisingly
similar to Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Approach of P. Huei, the first PDF of the page https://scholar.google.be/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=Approach+of+P.+Huei+in+general+relativity&btnG=